# Error : Missing VtkCommonCore-6.0.dll

Tags: c++, vtk

I am trying to run a program in cpp through visual studio 2012 and using Vtk . I make a cpp copy of the program and also CMakeLists.txt and configure it through CMake 2.8 and then I run solution file in VS2012. After building all , when I want to run the program ( Control+F5 ) it  says vtkcommoncore-6.0.dll is missing in your computer.

I was wondering , how to solve this problem ? If someone can address me , step by step .

Thanks

Comment: Are teh vtk dlls in your path? Or did you copy the vtk dlls to the same folder as your exe?

Answer (score 1):

vtkCommonCore-6.0.dll probably does not exist. Check to see if it's there in your vtk build folder first.

If not, either the file is corrupted or you have deleted it somehow. ALternatively, you may have stopped your build of VTK in VS2012 midway, or altered a  VTK module and not built it.

Build VTK again and then check.